# Player forfeiting a GKTurnBasedMatch

Tags: ios, gamekit

Say I have a GKTurnBasedMatch with 2 players, and the second one forfeited within his turn. How shall I display that to the first user to know the game has ended? Or maybe making the first player quit programmatically?

Another GKTurnBasedMatch- this time, 12 players. I didn't understand a thing here- say player 7 quits, it means that when the turn gets to him, it will stuck the game, and I will need to end that match programmatically to all of the users? Or maybe GC renumbers the remaining players accordingly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send one of the following to your GKTurnBasedMatch object:

```
- (void)participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:(GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome)matchOutcome
                        nextParticipants:(NSArray *)nextParticipants
                             turnTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout
                               matchData:(NSData *)matchData
                       completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler

- (void)participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:(GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome)matchOutcome
                      withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Calling `participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome` will send a turn event to the other players in the match to notify them that a player has quit. The player's object in match.participants will have matchOutcome `GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit`

Answer (score 0):

I've created an [game kit turn based match example project](https://bitbucket.org/tenseg/hellogamekitios) that illustrates quitting out of turn and quitting in turn. Take a look at the `quit()` function in the `GameModel.swift` file to see how to call these:

```
func quit(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    if isLocalPlayerTurn {
        let next = nextParticipants()
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
        match?.participantQuitInTurn(with: .quit, nextParticipants: next, turnTimeout: 600, match: data) { error in
            completionHandler(error)
        }
    } else {
        match?.participantQuitOutOfTurn(with: .quit) { error in
            completionHandler(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, checking to see whether someone has won is also important. Here is the `checkForWin()` function from this same file.

```
func checkForWin(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let stillPlaying = match?.participants?.filter({ $0.matchOutcome == .none }),
        stillPlaying.count == 1,
        stillPlaying[0].player?.playerID == currentPlayerID
        else {
            return completionHandler(false, nil)
    }

    stillPlaying[0].matchOutcome = .won
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)

    match?.endMatchInTurn(withMatch: data) { error in
        print("***** match ended")
        completionHandler(true, error)
    }
}
```

All this makes more sense in the context of the whole example project. I hope it helps.